# Core data won't save correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using a data model called settings which I setup in didLoad of my viewController:

```
settings = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Settings" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

Heres the managedobjectContext method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}
```

When my stepper increments I want to update a string and then update the db.

```
- (IBAction)RowStepperAction:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    double value = [sender value];
    settings.numberofrows = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value];
    [self.RowNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

When I come to load the view again I do:

```
[self.ColumnStepper setValue:[settings.numberofcolumns doubleValue]];
[self.RowStepper setValue:[settings.numberofrows doubleValue]];
```

This returns the default values I set in the database. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you load the view again, you're creating a brand new settings object :

```
settings = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Settings" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

This will have your default values. You need instead to fetch your existing settings object, and only create a new one if that doesn't exist.

Your database will currently have several settings objects, one for each time you've loaded the view.